# jQuery limit 1 item selection

Tags: jquery

I have 4 thumbnails showing (random images), and want to limit the selection to 1 item only and make the remaining thumbnails not selectable, unless you click the selected item to release it. To limit each user to 1 select, I was thinking of using .length < 1, but not sure how to limit 1.

CSS:

```
.item {
    height: 125px;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 125px;
}

.item:hover {
    background: #f00;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item-container">
    <a class="item" href="/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125">
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125">
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125">
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125">
    </a>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.item').addClass('inactive');

$('.item').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
        $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry... try to see how I can limit 1 selection and turn the others off.

Comment: What's the CSS for your in/active classes?

Comment: .active{color:blue;}.inactive{color:red;}

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way -

```
$('body').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( !$(this).hasClass('inactive') ) {
        $('.item').toggleClass('inactive');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j10xfjjm/

Comment: Thank you Jay for the help, can I ask what the '.item' inside of the .on() does/mean?

Comment: I'm just doing event delegation, you don't have to do that unless you're adding the `items` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasActive = false;

$('.item').addClass('inactive');

$('.item').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('inactive') && hasActive == false) {
        $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
        hasActive = true;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('active') {
        hasActive = false;
    }
});
```

Im sure there is a flaw in this code somewhere Im tired but the idea is set a flag to see if there is an active image and check it before allowing another active image.